# c++ std::vector<> vs new[] performance

Tags: c++, new-operator, stdvector

Is there any big difference in allocation, deallocation and access time between `std::vector<>` and `new[]` when both are fixed and same length?

Comment: There shouldn't be. The `std::vector`'s `operator []` would be inlined and the generated code should be fairly similar.

Comment: Profile it and see, but I would expect there to be no difference.

Comment: unless this is really performance critical (which I doubt; and access won't be), use `std::vector<>` and avoid raw pointers.

Comment: Even if it is there, which will be, it is negligible. Vector maintains and array list of elements. Whereas new allocates a memory location. Vector at the back end is also creating elements with new keyword. So, new's work is only to allocate, whereas the vector will not only be creating a new element but will also be organizing it into an array and incrementing size information and may be other things. So, in my opinion vector will be taking  slightly more time (in terms of reorganizing elements when one is deleted or added).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depends on the types and how you call it. `std::vector<int> v(1000000);` has to zero a million ints, whereas `new int[1000000];` doesn't, so I would expect a difference in speed. This is one place in `std::vector` where you might pay through the nose for something you don't use, if for some reason you don't care about the initial values of the elements.

If you compare `std::vector<int> v(1000000);` with `new int[1000000]();` then I doubt you'll see much difference. The significant question is whether one of them somehow has a more optimized loop setting the zeros, than the other one does. If so, then the implementation of the other one has missed a trick (or more specifically the optimizer has).

Comment: But `v(N)` and `new T[N]` are not comparable. You need to keep memory and objects separate. So the real comparison is with `std::vector<T> v; v.reserve(N);`. If anything, `vector` is better because it *allows* you to keep a clear mind about objects and memory.

Comment: @KerrekSB I agree with you but it could be argued the other way too: `T* t = new T[N]` allows you to say `t[n] = 42;`, whereas the `vector.reserve` counterpart doesn't.

Comment: @juanchopanza: No, but `t[n]` assumes that you already have a range of objects. I mean, yes, you *could* have some weird "uninitialized storage random access" use case in mind, but I believe that most actual, real-world algorithms will either require a sane, existing range, or otherwise build up a collection sequentially in some way. If you really needed, you could build an uninitialized random access interface, though.

Comment: @SteveJessop so i realized that `new[]` allocates big memory blocks faster while `std::vector<>` gives convenience. the methods have to have intersection when both are equivalent. the question is: does this intersection point linearly depends from machine power? if it's not does that mean that some method is superior?

Comment: It's not that `new[]` allocates big blocks faster. `new[]` has the option for trivial types to leave them all uninitialized and `vector` doesn't (you can `reserve` with vector as Kerrek says, but in order to use any index you must first initialize all lower indexes). So for certain limited purposes `new[]` can be faster, but you should not leave with the impression that it is usually faster.

Answer (score 3):

`new` is a bad thing, because it violates the idiom of *single responsibility* by assuming *two* respon­sibi­li­ties: Storage allocation *and* object construction. Complexity is the enemy of sanity, and you fight com­plexity by separating concerns and isolating responsibilities.

The standard library containers allow you to do just that, and only think about *objects*. Moreover, `std::vector` addionally allows you to think about storage, but *separately*, via the `reserve`/`capacity` interfaces.

So for the sake of keeping a clear mind about your program logic, you should always prefer a container such as `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<Foo> v;

// make some storage available
v.reserve(100);

// work with objects - no allocation is required
v.push_back(x);
v.push_back(f(1, 2));
v.emplace_back(true, 'a', 10);
```

Comment: In which sense do you use the term *object* here? (I'm slightly confused..)

Comment: @DyP: I guess in the sense of 3.8?

Comment: "The standard library containers allow you to do just that, and only think about *regions of storage*. Moreover, `std::vector` addionally allows you to think about storage, but separately, via the `reserve`/`capacity` interfaces." Simply search+replace doesn't work for me :( -- at least, it sounds confusing

Comment: Oh, wait, 3.8, not 1.8.